# Failed to connect to SonarQube server

Tags: sonarlint

When i am trying to connect to Sonarqube server from sonarlint test connection gui, it throws an exception:

```
Fail to request https://sonarqube.mycompany.com/api/system/status
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request https://sonarqube.mycompany.com/api/system/status  at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:212)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:154)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:143)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.SonarLintWsClient.rawGet(SonarLintWsClient.java:99)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.fetchServerInfos(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:96)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.checkVersionAndStatus(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:60)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.container.connected.validate.ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.checkVersionAndStatus(ServerVersionAndStatusChecker.java:50)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.WsHelperImpl.validateConnection(WsHelperImpl.java:48)
    at org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.WsHelperImpl.validateConnection(WsHelperImpl.java:43)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.server.Server.testConnection(Server.java:225)
    at org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.internal.server.wizard.ServerConnectionTestJob.run(ServerConnectionTestJob.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 404
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.createTunnel(RealConnection.java:300)
```

Comment: If you post the code you are using, it will be easier for people to help you find problems in it

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using ?

Comment: SonarQube version - 4.5.5

Comment: And which version of SonarLint ? (as a good practice just put the full context and version details in your question)

Comment: Same issue with SonarQube 4.5.7 and SonarLint 2.2.1. /api/system/status sends a 404, and the URL /api/webservices/list doesn't show this endpoint. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to the SonarQube Web Api, the endpoint api/system/status is only available since version 5.2.

It seems that your SonarLint version is no more compatible with your version of SonarQube. I have open this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/bkpPRzUyuNc

Link : https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/system